# How to calculate gross value of a column containing "null", positive and negative values on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I have the following table in SQL Server:

[image: ![![![enter image description here]

I am trying to group the table by columns "Portfolio" and "Date" and sum up Net Discrepancy. Also, I would like to add a new column named "Gross Discrepancy".

The "Gross Discrepancy" would be the same as NET Discrepancy if NET Discrepancy is a positive number. If Net Discrepancy is a negative number, then it should be multiplied by -1 in order to get a positive number. In short, I am looking for the result like below:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have been written the code below, which correctly calculates the aggregate NET_discrepancy but I am not able to figure out how to get the GROSS_discrepancy:

```
SELECT 
    date_long, portfolio, 
    SUM(ISNULL(CAST(NET_Discrepancy AS float), 0))
FROM 
    My_Table
GROUP BY
    date_long, Portfolio
ORDER BY
    date_long
```

Comment: [ABS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Side note, `float` may well not be the correct data type here; it is, in fact, *rarely* the correct data type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ABS function to get an absolute value
[Result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f0b3358f31f7b2adb2daada7f7b6d26)

```
select 
portfolio,
date_long,
sum(coalesce(net_discrepancy,0)) as "NET discrepancy",
abs(sum(coalesce(net_discrepancy,0))) as "GROSS discrepancy"
from my_table
group by portfolio,date_long
order by 1 desc,2 desc
```